# MySQL select one row, join multiple to it

Tags: mysql, join, one-to-many

I have a table named `sessions` setup like this:

```
#################################
# set    # timestamp  # session #
#################################
# 5      # 1306458002 # 11      #
# 3      # 1306473234 # 6       #
# 3      # 1305241207 # 3       #
...
#################################
```

I have a second table named `events` setup like this:

```
#######################
# session    # code   #
#######################
# 6          # 45     #
# 6          # -10    #
# 6          # 0      #
# 3          # 7      #
...
#######################
```

I need to select the latest session of a given set, then join the associated event codes on top of that one record. Most importantly though, I just need this information from suppling a set (here the set is 3):

```
########
# code #
########
# 45   #
# -10  #
# 0    #
########
```

Comment: This should be really simple, I'm just having issues for some reason. Been a long day.

Comment: u need latest session or need all session list of given `set`? OR u want all `code` of that latest `set`?

Comment: I need all of the events associated with the latest instance of a given set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select e.code
from events e
inner join sessions s
    on s.session = e.session
where s.set = <whatever set you want>
and s.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from sessions where set = s.set)
```

Comment: why using `WHERE` clause in inner query??

Comment: So it knows to choose timestamps related to that particular set and not the one from, say, set 5 if 3 is chosen.

Comment: Works great, filters by the correct column (timestamp instead of session), but takes 0.024 seconds on my data. Now it's time to choose between fast/possibly inaccurate and slow/definitely correct.

Comment: I mean, typically I'd only use the where clause in the inner query, but with timestamps allowing possible duplicate values it seemed wise to filter the outer query for the set that was needed first, before diving into which timestamp to pull.

Comment: Us same-first-namers gotta stick together :-P

Comment: I think it's a bit premature to draw any conclusions of performance. The tables may turn depending on the amount of data inthe different tables...

Comment: I'm doing these calls on a database with about 10gb of information; it may be different on smaller tables. I'm trying to optimize this now – after all of the necessary joins, it's slowed down to around a minute a query... sad day!

Comment: This is a correlated sub-query, try using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    e.code
from
    (select
        max(session) as session
    from
        sessions s
    where
        s.set = 3) ms
    inner join event e on e.session = ms.session
```

Comment: Good one ! +1 for using sub query

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Now just gotta cross my fingers that sessions never go back in time, since it's sorting by session instead of by timestamp.

Comment: Took 0.005 sec to execute on my data, now to see how well the other queries hold up.

Comment: @Ryan, sorry, I overlooked the timestamp. It's better not to take the risk of sorting by sessionid and use ryebr3ad's solution instead.